# C# lambda body to string

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I have the following lambda expression

```
    var expr = a => (a.Name == "Alex" && a.DateCreated < DateTime.Now.AddHours(2))
```

I want to get the expression body with runtime values in a string, if i call expr.Body.ToString() i get the following string in return.

```
    {((a.Name == "Alex") AndAlso (a.DateCreated < DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)))}
```

So just to clarify i expected to get the value of DateTime.Now.AddHours(2). I been spending the last couple of nights searching the web furiously without any results. This may be down to   me not knowing what to search for. Hope you guys will be able to help :)

Comment: *Why* did you expect to get the value of `DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)`?

Comment: Not sure if i was expecting or hoping, but my aim is to get the actual value of DateTime.Now.AddHours(2).

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to move the DateTime call out of the lambda:

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
Expression<Func<YourClass, bool>> expr = a => (a.Name == "Alex" && a.DateCreated < endDate);
```

Even then, you'll show the closure in the expression, not the value.

To get a specific date as a printed value, you'd need a constant, ie:

```
Expression<Func<YourClass, bool>> expr = a => (a.Name == "Alex" && a.DateCreated < DateTime.Parse("10/2/2012"));
```

This will show the `DateTime.Parse` call, but at least still show the value (since it's a constant in the expression.)

When you build an expression, the `DateTime` property and method (`Now` and `AddHours`) become part of the expression itself.  This happens with the closed variable, as well.  The expression has to include all of the statements required to build the full lambda, including `DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)`.

This is by design - `DateTime.Now.AddHours()` needs to be resolved on the server if you're turning this into an Entity Framework query, for example, as [AddHours is one of the Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx).  If this was swapped out with a constant, it would not behave as expected.

Comment: Now it gives me "value(Test.Program+()c_DisplayClass0).date" instead. Surely there must be a way to get the actual value of DateTime, instead of the name of the variable.

Yes that kind of puts a limit on what i was hoping to do with this.

Comment: Okay i'll have to rethink my solution i guess, really appreciate your quick reply on this :)

Comment: I'm playing around with Dapper and want the ability to write sql where clauses. At the moment i'm using anonymous types and reflection to do the job, this obviously has some limitations on the kind of clauses i can produce.

Comment: @AlexanderHansen You'd need to take the value() portion and actually get the value at runtime, when you convert to the SQL.  This is what happens by most providers for LINQ providers, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works, but I am not sure if you *really* want to use it.

```
Expression<Func<A,bool>> expr = a => (a.Name == "Alex" && a.DateCreated < DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));

var expr1 = expr.Body as BinaryExpression;
var expr2 = expr1.Right as BinaryExpression; //a.DateCreated < DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)
var expr3 = expr2.Right as MethodCallExpression; //DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)

var obj = expr3.Object as MemberExpression; //DateTime.Now
var pi = obj.Member as PropertyInfo;
var dt = pi.GetValue(null); //Call DateTime.Now


var arg = expr3.Arguments[0] as ConstantExpression;
var result = expr3.Method.Invoke(dt, new object[] { arg.Value }); //Call AddHours
```

-

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, seems to be working just fine. But then again it won't really work on more complex expressions. But thanks alot, this might just point me in the right direction :)